# How to Iterate a Registry Folder using Batch Script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

I am new to batch scripting.I was trying to write a batch file to iterate through all the string values kept at the registry location **HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Folders**. And find the result of certain condition. Where the condition is like : a String value with 'Name' field ending with 'Office14'".And I also want to store the 'Name' field of the registry value where the name is ending with 'Office14'.Here is the code which I was using.

```
    @echo OFF

    set KEY_NAME="HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Folders"
    set OFFICE=OFFICE14\
    set RESULT="NOT FOUND"

    FOR %%A IN ('REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Folders"') DO (
       set ValueName=%%A
       REM Getting 9 characters from right i.e OFFICE14\ and comparing it to %OFFICE%
       set ValueName=%ValueName:~-9%
       IF %ValueName%==%OFFICE% (
           set RESULT="FOUND"
           goto :NEXT
       )
    )
    : NEXT
     echo %RESULT%
```

But the result here is always 'Not Found'. Can anybody help me to fix this code or point me to some helpful documentation for doing the same.

Thanks.

EDIT: Complete value of name (which ends with Office14) is to be stored in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Folders"|find /i "\Office14\" >nul 2>&1 && set "RESULT=FOUND"
echo %RESULT%
```

---

appended *after the question is answered*:

target string is:

```
     C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\     REG_SZ
```

getting the path name here is a bit difficult because of trailing spaces/tabs. I suggest a solution with [sed for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Folders"^|sed -nr "/\\Office14\\/Is/\s+(.*)\s+REG_SZ/\1/p"') do SET "OFFICEPATH=%%~a"
echo %OFFICEPATH%
```

---

And a more advanced solution without `sed`:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Folders"^|find /i "\Office14\"') do SET "OFFICEPATH=%%a"
SET "right=REG_SZ%OFFICEPATH:*REG_SZ=%"
CALL SET "OFFICEPATH=%%OFFICEPATH:%right%=%%"
:loop
SET "OFFICEPATH=%OFFICEPATH:~0,-1%"
IF "%OFFICEPATH:~-1%"==" " GOTO :loop
ECHO "%OFFICEPATH%"
```

Comment: @Enduro Thanks a lot.One more question, is it possible to fetch the 'Name' field of the registry value , where the match is found.As I also need to store the 'Name' field of the Registry entry.

Comment: This was NOT part of your original question. Follow the rules of SO and simply make a new question.

Comment: @Enduro I am sorry as I forgot to mention it in the original question.But I have now edited the question. Can you please provide any pointers for this as well.

Comment: @Enduro Thanks. I was trying the code without 'sed', and on my system it is returning "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\Cultures\". I was expecting it to return the path till  OFFICe14. Do I require to make any other change in the code provided by you ?